# What is the use of the arroba in "@advertencia" after a threatening letter?

Tags: puntuación

I am trying to understand the use of the arroba. Is this mark used more commonly in some countries than others?

I saw a threatening letter in which the final thing written was:

> @advertencia

What does this mean?

Comment: We need more context. As written, it sounds like a random character used to emphasize what goes next, as if they would write `!advertencia` or `+advertencia`. I have never seen it in Spain.

Comment: I would say someone was trying to be cool and modern, and instead of *#advertencia* wrote *@advertencia*.

Comment: For me it would look like a typo.

Comment: @Paco Is *#advertencia* common usage?

Comment: @Jacinto It is, at least in Spain.

Comment: @Paco All right. What does it mean? Is it used with other words as well? Maybe I should ask a question about it...

Comment: @Jacinto Feel free, and of course add some more context to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays it is quite typical to use some kind of rare-but-familiar character to emphasize *what goes next (see?).

*Arroba* has become quite successful among Spanish speaking people to mark both genders. Hopefully we will get rid of these soon, but it is still quite typical to see *bienvenid@s*, *amig@s* and similar instead of the traditional *bienvenidos/as*, *amigos/as*. As always, new fancy characters get adopted fast because people like to use them and tweak their common usage.

In this case, I do believe that it was used just as a character to express attention, while it could also be a bad interpretation of the `@` in comments, Twitter, etc.

All in all, this is not normative and you just have to see them as a way to catch your attention... in another way.

Compare these two:

> Rogamos no dejen la basura en el rellano.
>
> Rogamos no dejen la basura en el rellano. @advertencia

To me, the second one sounds more furious and I would take it more seriously.